# Insert a value based on id from two different tables

Tags: sql, t-sql

I got a huge question.

I'm trying to migrate some data from an existent table to a new one. I'm having troubles to figure out how to do the following :

In the Address table there are two columns:

```
 AddressTable
 ---------------------------------------------
 StateCode(nvarchar) and CountryCode(nvarchar)
```

Both hold a two letter code for states and countries codes.

Now in the new table we made two foreign keys

```
 NewAddressTable
 ---------------------
 StateId and CountryId
```

That correspond to two tables State and Country

```
StateTable has (Id,(FK)IdCountry,Name,Code)
CountryTable has (Id,Name,Code)
```

What I'm trying to do is based on the state and country code on the Address table how can I add replace the values from the old table with the new ones based on the state and code.

An example:

```
AddressTable
-------------
City        StateCode   PostalCode  CountryCode
North Haven CT          06473       US

NewAddressTable
---------------
IdCountry   IdState
236         8

CountryTable
--------------- 
Id   Name           Code
236  UNITED STATES  US

StateTable
--------------
Id   IdCountry  Name            Code
8    236            CONNECTICUT CT
```

Thank you.

Comment: Your old address table should also get the country and state id from your new tables? If so does it mean you haveto create new field for that or put it in statecode and countrycode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work.

```
insert into newtable
(idCountry, idState)
select country.id, state.id
from oldtable join country on oldtable.CountryCode = Country.Code
join state on oldtable.stateCode = state.code
```